# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name must be specified as one of stress, prod, prod-p, dev, test, int, dr

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Recently I tried to upgrade my application (maven) to Spring boot version to 2.7.3 and Spring version 5.3.22. After upgrading the version I am getting the below error while starting the application.
Java version 1.8

Previous versions

Spring boot - 2.0.9.RELEASE

Spring - 5.0.13.RELEASE

```
[ERROR] - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name must be specified as one of stress, prod, prod-p, dev, test, int, dr
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:136) ~[commons-lang-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at com.expedia.www.platform.configuration.spring.SpringEnvironment.createEnvironment(SpringEnvironment.java:49) ~[platform-configuration-spring-2.0.23.jar:local]
    at com.expedia.www.platform.configuration.spring.SpringEnvironment.postProcessBeanFactory(SpringEnvironment.java:38) ~[platform-configuration-spring-2.0.23.jar:local]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:183) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.expedia.www.eps.auxiliary.Starter.main(Starter.java:46) [classes/:?]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  29.701 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-28T16:52:57+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.3:run (default-cli) on project eps-auxiliary-service: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Here is my pom.xml snippet

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.jdk.version>${java.version}</project.jdk.version>
        <project.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <start-class>com.expedia.www.eps.auxiliary.Starter</start-class>

        <!-- Following properties are for release. -->
        <buildType>sandbox</buildType>
        <buildNumber>0</buildNumber>
        <buildBranch>local</buildBranch>
        <changeNumber>local</changeNumber>
        <depotInfo>none</depotInfo>
        <buildTime>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTime>

        <spring-boot.version>2.7.3</spring-boot.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.22</spring.version>
        <aws.version>1.10.22</aws.version>
        <metrics-servlet.version>3.1.2</metrics-servlet.version>
        <platform-monitoring.version>1.2.0</platform-monitoring.version>
        <platform-isactive.version>1.1.18</platform-isactive.version>
        <platform-build-tools.version>0.1.49</platform-build-tools.version>
        <fasterxml.jackson.version>2.13.2</fasterxml.jackson.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>

        <findbugs-maven-plugin.version>3.0.4</findbugs-maven-plugin.version>
        <findbugs.include.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/include.xml</findbugs.include.filter.location>
        <findbugs.exclude.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/exclude.xml</findbugs.exclude.filter.location>
        <maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.5</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
        <pmd.version>5.3.2</pmd.version>
        <pmd.ruleset.location>${project.basedir}/buildtools/ruleset.xml</pmd.ruleset.location>
        <pmd.skip>false</pmd.skip>

        <!-- spring boot -->
        <debug.port>5000</debug.port>
        <run.jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dapplication.home=. -Dapplication.name=${project.name}
            -Dapplication.environment=dev -Dproject.name=${project.name} -Xdebug
            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debug.port}
        </run.jvmArguments>

        <error-inspector.version>0.1.9</error-inspector.version>
        <platform-diagnostics.version>1.1.5</platform-diagnostics.version>

        <!-- Jacoco code coverage -->
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/*HttpConfiguration.java</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--
                explicit override for the log4j2 vulnerability;
                this can be removed once newer spring boot version released with the fix;
                this HAS TO be defined before the default spring boot dependencies.
            -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-transit</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www</groupId>
            <artifactId>offerservice-sdk-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.88-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-configuration-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-isactive</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-isactive.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-monitoring</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-monitoring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www</groupId>
            <artifactId>springboot-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-diagnostics</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-diagnostics.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mikesamuel</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia.ews</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-partner</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia.ews</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-filters</artifactId>
            <version>3.20</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Here is my pom.xml

Comment: Please [edit] the question, don't try to add your whole pom.xml inside a comment because 1) It won't fit; 2) Even if it did, it would be unreadable.

Comment: Anyway, how are you running this? Looks like something is expecting a parameter you're not passing. And it seems like something related to whatever `com.expedia.www.platform.configuration.spring.SpringEnvironment.createEnvironment` is, rather than Spring itself.

Comment: I'm unable to add my pom to the question getting these errors.
Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 40240.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Run Command
 mvn spring-boot:run -Dapplication.name=auxiliary-service -Dapplication.home=. -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dapplication.environment=dev

Comment: Looks to me it's talking about `-Dapplication.name=auxiliary-service` and its value is neither of those you cited in the title (or it's about some other property called `name` you're not even passing). Again, this seems to be specific to some library you're using (and you're not mentioning) rather than Spring itself.